# podman error: tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake

Tags: linux, docker, proxy, podman

on a server with Podman installed.

I connected to the Internet through a proxy server.

```bash
export http_proxy=https://proxy.domain.addr:1234/
export https_proxy=https://proxy.domain.addr:1234/
```

it's works.

For Docker, I use [this solution](https://docs.docker.com/config/daemon/systemd/) and it works.

However, when I use podman, I get the following error:

```
tcp: tls: first record does not look like a TLS handshake
```

I tried to do this

```bash
export http_proxy=https://proxy.domain.addr:1234/
export https_proxy=https://proxy.domain.addr:1234/

podman build --tls-verify=false --http-proxy=true ...
```

as well as another solution available on the Internet.

But almost all solutions refer to Docker, not Podman :-(

My server:

```
podman: 1.6.4
docker: 20.10.17, build 100c701
OS: rhel 7.9 (Maipo)
```

Maybe someone knows about this problem.

Thanks

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Super User](https://superuser.com/) would be better places to ask this question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have specified an `https://` URL in the `export http_proxy=` variable. I don’t know why it works for some things but not others, but it looks like Podman depends on the `http_proxy` variable actually being an `http://` URL.